# how to pass a target database on H2 database console

Tags: h2

I'm using H2 database console as a servlet in my own web application that provides a front end of many databases.

How to skip or help a login step at H2 database console by passing some parameters in my own code?
(I have *many* databases, so I won't use "saved settings" first.)

imaginary: http://myapp/h2console/login.do?user=scott&password=tiger&url=jdbc:thin:......

Answer (score 0):

Because of the somewhat special session handling of the console, this is not possible just using an fixed URL. (The session handling allows to open multiple connections within multiple tabs from one browser, which is not possible when using cookies.)

However, what you can do is create a URL in the same way as [Server.startWebServer(Connection conn)](http://h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/tools/Server.html#startWebServer_Connection) does:

```
// the server is already running in your case,
// so most likely you don't need the following lines:
WebServer webServer = new WebServer();
Server web = new Server(webServer, new String[] { "-webPort", "0" });
web.start();
Server server = new Server();
server.web = web;
webServer.setShutdownHandler(server);

// this will create a new session and return the URL for it: 
String url = webServer.addSession(conn);
```